# Research at the county-level: Macro or Micro?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, applied-econometrics, urban-economics

Is research at the county-level considered applied micro or applied micro?

The standard undergrad definitions (**"micro" = "individual"**, **"macro" = "nation"**) are of no help with units of measurement that lie in between.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it's miacro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the focus of the research and the type of model(s) applied.

A study of a particular good or industry at county level would be **micro**. This might include consideration of, for example, demand and supply of a good, the degree of competition in an industry, and the effect of a tax or subsidy on production or sale of a good.

A study of the overall level of economic activity in a county would be **macro**.  This might include consideration of, for example, consumption and saving out of income by residents of the county, investment and public expenditure within the county, "exports" to and "imports" from neighbouring counties and beyond, and the effects of all of these on the county's overall economic activity.

Comment: Ah! This is such an excellent answer that it has made me happy I've even asked this question here. This is econ stackexchange gold! Thanks!

Comment: According to this definition of macro, this is EXACTLY my approach and what i want to do with my reserach! Thanks, @Adam Bailey!

Answer (score 3):

I would consider county-level research macroeconomics.

Microeconomics focuses on individuals and firms acting as decision makers. I think, looking at county-level aggregates, you are too high level to look at decision makers.